# Qual è l'origine del vocabolo "zanni" per i servi della commedia dell'arte?

Tags: etymology

Recentemente sono andata a vedere il balletto *Pulcinella* di Igor Stravinskij in versione concerto. Prima del concerto vi hanno spiegato cos'erano i zanni, i personaggi dei servi nella commedia dell’arte. Questo nome, "zanni", mi è sembrato molto curioso e mi sono chiesta da dove provenisse. Ho cercato informazioni su [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanni) e sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/zanni/). Nel Treccani ho trovato

> propr. *Zanni*, forma toscanizzata del veneto *Zani*, corrispondente al tosc. *Gianni*, ipocoristico del nome proprio *Giovanni*.

E su Wikipedia ho letto:

> Il nome di Zanni, come Zuan, è una versione veneta del nome Gianni, un nome molto diffuso nel contado veneto-lombardo da dove venivano la maggior parte dei servitori dei nobili e dei ricchi mercanti veneziani.

La mia domanda è: sapreste dirmi qualcosa sul perché di questo nome proprio, Zanni o Zuan, nella commedia dell’arte? C'è stato forse qualche personaggio con questo nome?

Comment: un parlante nativo direbbe preferibilmente "andata a sentire", o molto più facilmente "andata a vedere". Meglio ancora: "sono stata a vedere". Se non ricordo male c'era una domanda a proposito qualche tempo fa :)

Comment: @TobiaTesan: Grazie mille, ho fatto la correzione!

Comment: E visto che non è stato citato, ci sta bene [lo zanni in grammelot di Dario Fo](https://youtu.be/qfG20CGd_AI).

Comment: @DaG: Adesso ho scoperto che il testo in grammelot di *La fame dello Zanni* (non esattamente le stesse parole del video, ma la stessa storia) si trova nel libro *Mistero buffo*, pubblicato da Einaudi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ci sono due spiegazioni diverse sull'origine di questo termine.
*[Il Vocabolario Etimologico di Pianigiani](http://etimo.it/?term=zanni&find=Cerca)* (1907) suggerisce a) provenienza latina, e b) provenienza dal nome del villano bergamasco:

[image]

La prima versione è più vecchia e corrisponde a quello che scrive Vincenzo De Amicis nel libro *[L'imitazione latina nella commedia italiana del XVI secolo](https://books.google.se/books?id=H5_zAAAAMAAJ&dq=Il%20nome%20stesso%20di%20Zanni%20dato%20alle%20maschere%20della%20commedia%20dell'arte%2C%20ne%20indica%20appunto%20la%20origine%2C%20ch%C3%A8%20esso%20non%20%C3%A8%20altro%20che%20il%20latino%20Sannio&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (1871, p.20):

> Il nome stesso di Zanni dato alle maschere della commedia dell'arte, ne indica appunto la origine, chè esso non è altro che il latino Sannio <...>.

[image]

E così scrive anche Francesco Saver Quadrio in *[Storia e della Ragione d'Ogni Poesia](https://books.google.se/books?id=9_tsTzg6sVoC&pg=PA213#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (1744, II, p. 213):

> Dico adunque, che la voce Zanni è a noi derivata originalmente dal Greco *Sannos*, voce da Gratino, e da altri Greci usata, a lignificare uno stolto, o scempio, dalla quale trassero i Latini Cornici la lor voce *Sannio*, e *sanniu*. <...> E perché appunto quelli Scempi, e Stolti fanno con le lor positure, aspetti, e gesti, mille morfie, onde movere il riso, disse però ottimamente Tullio cosi scrivendo: "E che ci può essere tanto ridicolo, quanto un Sannione, il quale con la bocca, col volto, con imitare i movimenti, con la voce, finalmente con tutto il corpo è motivo di riso?"

[image]

La seconda spiegazione, proprio quella che viene suggerita in tutti i dizionari moderni, è più recente. Per esempio, [dizionario](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=zanni) di De Mauro e Mancini:

> zanni
>   1. personaggio della commedia dell’arte che rappresenta il servo scaltro e imbroglione, oppure il servo sciocco o finto sciocco dalle trovate burlesche e ridicole
>   2. (non com.) buffone, pagliaccio: *fare lo zanni*
>   **Etimologia** ← forma toscanizzata del ven. *zani*, riduzione dial. del nome proprio *giovanni*.

Questa spiegazione viene attribuita a Carlo Dati, come citato da Gilles Ménage nel libro *[Le origine della Lingua Italiana](https://books.google.se/books?id=iIVMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA498#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (1685, p.498):

> ZANI. ZANNI. Buffone. Dissi nelle mie origini Francesi, che questo vocabolo Italiano derivava dal Greco-Barbaro sanniu, voce dello stesso significato. E questo è anche il sentimento di quel gran Letterato Claudio Salmasio, sopra l'istoria Augusta. <..> Ora sono del parere del Signor Carlo Dati, quel celebre Accademico della Crusca, a cui tanto debbono le Lettere Toscane, il quale tien per fermo che sia stata corrotta questa voce da quella di Giovanni.

Ménage poi recita la lettera completa di Carlo Dati (che è troppo lunga per riprodurla qui) e conclude che "Sig. Ferrari seguita il Salmasio" (cioè Ottavio Ferrari nelle *Origini della lingua Italiana*), ma che Ménage stesso non è "di parere di cangiar sentimento".

Quadrio, menzionato sopra, è molto scettico per quanto riguarda la provenienza di questo termine dal nome Giovanni:

> Io ben so, che Carlo Dati, riferito dal Menagio, l'ha creduto che quello nome di Zanni fosse derivato da Giovanni, che in Lingua Toscana per abbreviazione si dice Gianni, e che i Lombardi dicono Zanni, conghietturando che forse per essersi uno de' primi Arlichini chiamato Giovanni sia rimesa questa denominazione a tutti gli altri susseguiti Arlichini. Io non mi maraviglio pero tanto di esso Dati, che abbia abbondonata la primiera etimologia <...>

... ma, ovviamente, l'opinione di Dati, uno degli Accademici della Crusca, ha guadagnato più rispetto e credibilità.

**TL;DR** La spiegazione vecchia è che *zanni* proviene dalla voce latina *sannio* con lo stesso significato. La versione "moderna" è stata introdotta nel 1685 e insiste che Zanni non significhi altro che Giovanni (=Gianni), come si pronuncia in Lombardia e per lo più a Bergamo. Gli esperti in etimologia e nella storia dell'arte hanno considerato credibili tutte e due versioni.

Comment: I.M., ci sono fonti contemporanee che danno credito alla versione “sannita” di Zanni?

Comment: @DaG, non credo. La domanda mi ha incuriosito tantissimo, ho passato ben due giorni su Google. Ci sono fonti contemporanee, sia italiane che inglesi, che menzionano tutte e due versione, mai solo quella "sannita". Guarda, per esempio, [qua](https://books.google.se/books?id=yLtoRB9Wy-sC&lpg=PA148&ots=WpQAPBpW2V&pg=PA148#v=onepage&q&f=false) o [qua](https://books.google.se/books?id=BUGLBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA115&pg=PA115#v=onepage&q&f=false). Poi ci sono anche un paio di libri che parlano esclusivamente delle origini di zanni. Ho messo i link nel commento sotto, non so se riuscissi a trovargli...

Comment: @DaG, ecco i link: [un libro](https://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=Fmt0Ve6ZM4qAywP2ggI) e [un articolo](http://rebus.let.uniroma1.it/easyweb/w8017/index.php?EW_T=M1&EW_FL=w8017/ew_limiti.html&EW4_DLL=10&EW4_DLP=10&EW4_NVR=&EW4_NVT=&EW4_NMI=&EW4_CJL=1&NOICONE=1&PHPMSG=1&MEMORICE=1&lang=fra&lang=fra&lang=fra&lang=fra&lang=fra&lang=fra&lang=fra&EW_RM=10&EW_EP=REF601=MNT00037487&EW_RP=9&&EW_P=LSPHP&EW_D=W8017&EW=0206289).

Comment: ... e poi c'è una Anna Moro che [riporta l’etimologia](http://www.ajol.info/index.php/issa/article/view/89544) della parola "zanni" dall’arabo medievale "zanj" - "lavoratore, ovvero servo proveniente dall’Africa orientale"... (Mi fermo qua credo, basta versioni, grazie...)

Comment: Grazie per il lavorone, I.M.!

Answer (score 4):

Alle fonti citate da I.M. aggiungo quello che scrivevano Carlo Battisti e Giovanni Alessio nel loro *Dizionario etimologico* (1966):

> personaggio ridicolo della commedia bergamasca, arlecchino; ‘Giovanni’. È il nome con cui nel XVI sec. si chiamavano i servi bergamaschi. Cfr. il piem. *gianàs* sciattone e i diversi *zaneìn*, *s'oanìn*, *zanìn* l'acaro del formaggio. Ne dipende il rom[ano] ‘zagnotta’. Nel Lippi (a. 1676) e nel Magalotti (1667) *nanni*, con assimilazione e col senso di minchione. Cfr. ‘giandùia’. – Il calabrese n'ha dedotto un verbo *z'annïari* burlare. – Il vecchio collegamento coi *sanniones* delle atellane (a. 1669, Perrucci) fu già combattuto da Carlo Dati.

Il più recente Cortelazzo-Zolli conferma l'ipotesi “Giovanni”, con un possibile variante, e dà per superate altre tra cui quella “sannita”:

> Dal n[ome] pr[oprio] *Zanni* ‘Giovanni’. Già il T[ommaseo-]B[ellini] [spiegava](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items/120471): “è voce bergamasca, accorciata dall'intero nome Giovanni, che rappresenta un Servo semplice e goffo bergamasco” e Migl[iorini] *[Dal] N[ome ]P[roprio al nome comune]* 226, accettando questa spiegaz[ione], accennava all'inverosimilità di vedere nel n[ome] della maschera il lat[ino] *Sannio*. Tuttavia, il problema dell'orig[ine] remota resta, così, aperto. Una possibile soluzione è stata proposta da L. Lazzerini, *Preistoria degli Zanni: mito e spettacolo nella coscienza popolare* (negli Atti del Convegno su *Scienze, credenze occulte, livelli di cultura*, Firenze, 1982, pp. 445-475), che ritiene, con l'appoggio di una appropriata documentazione, che *Giovanni* si sia sovrapposto a *Zan*, continuatore di *Dianus*, corrispondente m[aschile] di *Diana*, diventata un ‘essere demoniaco’ presso le popolazioni romane cristianizzate. Inutile richiamare una eventuale contaminazione con *zana* ‘cesta’, ma anche ‘chi s'incaricava di recapitare qualcosa dietro commissione e a pagamento’, come ha il Machiavelli in una lettera a Francesco Vettori del 25 febbraio 1514 (R[ivista ]D[ialettale] I 1975 466-467). – Bibl[iografia] sul personaggio: V. Pandolfi, *La commedia dell'arte*, I, Firenze, 1957, pp. 155-293.

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, questa fonte sembra non dare retta alla provenienza latina da *Sannio*.

Comment: @Charo: Infatti, e anche tutti i dizionari recenti che ho visto concordano su “Giovanni” etc. Qualcuno ha il Cortelazzo-Zolli sotto mano?

Comment: Sarebbe interessante consultarlo. Per poter farlo, io dovrei andare alla biblioteca della Facoltà di Lettere, che è a 7 km di casa mia.

Comment: DaG, Grande Dizionario Etimologico di De Mauro e Mancini concorda su Zanni=Giovanni: *[Etimologia](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=zanni) ← forma toscanizzata del ven. zani, riduzione dial. del nome proprio giovanni*

Comment: @Charo, nella mia risposta ho aggiunto il libro che sembra la fonte principale sulle origini di *zanni* dal nome Giovanni.

Comment: @Charo, ho aggiunto la voce del Cortelazzo-Zolli.

Comment: @I.M., come sopra. (Scusate lo spam, ma non si può notificare con la chiocciola un commento a più di una persona.)

Comment: @DaG: Grazie mille!

Comment: @DaG, interessante! Grazie mille!